# Compiler jumping function if, else if

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem: when I use my function, the compiler jumps over the call to it. 
I tried stepping through my program in the debugger, but it jump jumps over the function call.

Why is the function call skipped?

I do this:

```
void VoltageToPercent(short int Voltage, short int output){

 if((Voltage < 400) | (Voltage > 300)){
    output = 10;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 700)|(Voltage < 850)  ){
    output = 20;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 1100)|(Voltage < 1300) ){
    output = 30;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 1400)|(Voltage < 1800)){
    output = 40;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 1900)|(Voltage < 2200) ){
    output = 50;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 2300)|(Voltage < 2700) ){
    output = 60;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 2700)|(Voltage < 3100)){
    output = 70;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 3200) | (Voltage < 3600)){
    output = 80;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 3300) | (Voltage < 4100)){
    output = 90;
 }
 else if((Voltage > 4200) | (Voltage < 4600)){
    output = 100;

 }
}
```

Comment: `(Voltage < 400) | (Voltage > 300)`->`(Voltage < 400) || (Voltage > 300)`

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what "compiler every jump it" means.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @coderredoc You might want to rethink that condition.

Comment: @melpomene.: And I don't want to feed everything in a comment ...it will be AND. :)

Comment: I mean, when I stepping the program, the compiler skips the function.

Comment: How many voltages do not satisfy one of "less than 400" or "greater than 300"?  Did you intend "and" rather than "or"?  And regardless of whether you intended "and" or "or", you chose the bitwise operator, not the boolean operator, and that is unlikely to be a good idea (though, if the conditions are OK, it does work — each comparison generates 0 or 1, and those can be checked with `&` or `|`, but it more sensible to use `&&` or `||`).

Comment: Another serious problem with this code is that writing to the parameter `output` has _no effect_ on the caller.  C doesn't have out-parameters.  The debugger may be "jumping" the function because the compiler discarded all of its code as unnecessary!  You should return a value instead.

Comment: And the actual reason that the function is skipped is because the optimizer detects that it does nothing useful.  It doesn't return a value.  It doesn't change any variables outside the function.  Your `output` parameter is just a conveniently initialized local variable — you should either change the function to return an `int` and add `return output` at the end (and drop `output` as a parameter; make it a local variable only) or make the `output` parameter into a pointer and use `*output = …` throughout the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with code lines like:

```
if((Voltage < 400) | (Voltage > 300)){
```

1) A single `|` is a **binary or** which is not what you want. If you want a logical or do `||`

2) However, the logic is wrong. It will always be true. You write: "if a number is less than 400 or greater than 300". All numbers fulfil that! So the expression is always true.

You probably want a **logical and** (`&&`) like:

```
if((Voltage < 400) && (Voltage > 300)){
```

Comment: Note that the binary operator does work because the result of each comparison is 0 or 1.  However, that loses the benefit of any short-circuit evaluation.  The logical operators should be used in preference to the bitwise operators in this code.  The primary problem is that the or's should be and's.

Comment: Also notice the [optimization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856013/compiler-jumping-function-if-else-if#comment84715766_48856013).

Answer (score 1):

A couple things wrong here. First of all, as sg7 said, you're using the binary OR, rather than the logical OR you should be using ||. The different is that binary OR will take the bits, and apply an OR operation to them. For example:

```
(01001) | (01010)
```

Will result in

```
01011
```

But what you want is the logical operators. So for that you would just add another pipe so it looks like `Voltage > 5 || Voltage < 10`.

However, I'm guessing by your program, that you don't want to ask if it's greater than 700 OR less than 850, but rather that it is both greater than 700 AND less than 850. I'm guessing what's making it seem to you that it's skipping is that the first operation will always resolve to true. No matter what number you choose, it will always be either less than 400, or greater than 300.

So what you'd want instead is something like `if(Voltage < 400 && Voltage > 300)`

Whenever you have these sorts of issues just plug in a number and walk through the program yourself, and the answer will be pretty obvious!

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here are a lot of C operators that could help you out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators

Comment: Note that the binary operator does work because the result of each comparison is 0 or 1.  However, that loses the benefit of any short-circuit evaluation.  The logical operators should be used in preference to the bitwise operators in this code.  The primary problem is that the or's should be and's.

Comment: Also notice the [optimization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856013/compiler-jumping-function-if-else-if#comment84715766_48856013).